# Java REST API failing on error 400 - header not defined correctly

Tags: java, restful-authentication

I have written this code to preform POST call but keep failing on error 400
when i debugged i checked the header map and see that the Api-Key is not there

```
    URL url = new URL("URL");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Api-Key", "token");
        String input = Dispatcher.getGson().toJson(deliveryEstimateRequest); //using gson to [aer
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(input.length()));
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode() + " message " + conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Maybe it's a problem of your webserver, which does not accept custom http-headers?

Just try
`conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`

Comment: The problem was the date format so it failed on their size, 
The problem was that i found it in their logs so the response was not clear.